# Dropdown is getting disabled after the first rendering

Tags: reactjs, react-redux

I have a `Dropdown`, I select a value, lets say "myName", then I have a button that I click and it will display a form to fill with "myName" in one of the fields. But there is a UI issue. When I click that form button it display the form but the Dropdown selected item will disappear.
I tried debugging and it seems there is an issue when rendering it for second time. it fails in a function called  `commitRoot(root, finishedWork);` in `react-dom.js` file and I don't know what it means as i'm very new in this area.

```
    render() {
    return (
        <Dropdown 
            className='titlebar__dropdown'
            options={this.myOptions}
            onChange={this.selectedNameChanged}
            selectedKey={PlanSelector.selectedName}
            placeholder='Select a Plan'
        />
```

before clicking the form:

[image]

After clicking, and it doesn't show the options anymore:

[image]

Comment: could you please share your selectedNameChanged method and method that you are calling on form button click?

Answer (score 0):

You are probably overwriting the state of the property holding the value of the dropdown.

Make sure it is not again set to "" as you must have kept.

On the click of the button, the state is changed and as a result, render() is ran again because of which it is getting overwritten make sure to hold your state when the button is clicked and check if you are changing the state of selectedNameChanged property.

Hopefully, this helps,if not can you please provide the method which is called on button click.

Thanks